# How to avoid expressions of Zeros and how to reinsert results in a Module

Tags: mathematical-optimization, warning-messages

Here i have just a short example of my actual problem

```
x = Table[Subscript[y, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 11}];
x[[1, 1]] = 12;
x[[1, 2]] = 22;
x[[1, 3]] = 1;
x[[1, 4]] = 2;
x[[1, 5]] = 5;
x[[1, 6]] = 8 ;
x[[1, 7]] = 4;
x[[1, 8]] = 9;
x[[1, 9]] = 19;
x[[1, 10]] = 20;
x[[1, 11]] = 50;

x[[2, 1]] = 12;
x[[2, 2]] = 22;
x[[2, 3]] = 13;
x[[2, 4]] = 11;
x[[2, 5]] = 0;
x[[2, 6]] = 0;
x[[2, 7]] = 5;
x[[2, 8]] = 6;
x[[2, 9]] = 19;
x[[2, 10]] = 20;
x[[2, 11]] = 0;

x[[3, 1]] = 0;
x[[3, 2]] = 0;
x[[3, 3]] = 13;
x[[3, 4]] = 11;
x[[3, 5]] = 5;
x[[3, 6]] = 8;
x[[3, 7]] = 5;
x[[3, 8]] = 10;
x[[3, 9]] = 19;
x[[3, 10]] = 20;
x[[3, 11]] = 0;

T[x[[i = 1]]] := Module[{},

  Res = (Log[x[[i, 2]]/x[[i, 1]]]/(
     2*\[Pi]*x[[i, 10]])) + (Log[x[[i, 3]]/x[[i, 2]]]/(
     2*\[Pi]*x[[i, 10]])) + (Log[x[[i, 4]]/x[[i, 3]]]/(
     2*\[Pi]*x[[i, 10]])) + (Log[x[[i, 5]]/x[[i, 4]]]/(
     2*\[Pi]*x[[i, 10]]));

  P = Res + (x[[i, 6]]*x[[i, 7]])/x[[i, 8]];

  P*x[[i, 9]] + x[[i, 11]] + T[x[[i=1,2,3...]]]

  ]
T[x[[i]]]
```

`Res`represent physically representative Resistors which occure again or disappear in some rows of my matrix. This is not shown in this short example given. But in my actual problem i have a i=30, j=35 matrix and many more resistors. For an better overview i want to put every Resistor in my calculation of `Res`. As i do so, of course mathematica returns me an error, because some expression equal 0 or get divided by 0. Is there a way, that mathematica skips the expression of 0 within `Res`, so i become for every row within my Matrix a result?

Furthmore i try to reinsert the result of `T[[x[i=1]]` in `T[[x[i=2]]`, `T[[x[i=2]]`in `T[[x[i=3]]` and so on, thats why i wrote `T[x[[i=1,2,3...]]]` in the very end of my code. Is there also a simple way? Runnung a loop?

Thank you very much in advance!! :)

Comment: There are many syntactical errors along with some ill-formed programming techniques here, but worry not, things can be done better, and we can help you learn what you can do to fix this! If no one beats me to it, I’ll see what I can do in about 12-13 hours from now.

Comment: If there is a better way you can show me, i would be so grateful. I am trying to solve this, but can´t find a way for a while now.  Thank you so much.